# Get instance of a class in a discriminated union with its specific type, rather than the union type

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

Is there a nice way to have a function that creates a new instance of a class based on the value of the shared property you pass to it, and have it return the specific type of the instance created, rather than the union type? Taking and tweaking slightly the typescript docs example with shapes:

```
class Square {
    kind: "square";
    size: number;
}
class Rectangle {
    kind: "rectangle";
    width: number;
    height: number;
}
class Circle {
    kind: "circle";
    radius: number;
}

type Kinds = "circle" | "rectangle" | "square";
type Shape = Square | Rectangle | Circle;

function createShape(kind: Kinds) {
    switch (kind) {
        case "circle":
            return new Circle();
        case "rectangle":
            return new Rectangle();
        case "square":
            return new Square();
    }
}

createShape("circle").radius; //Property 'radius' does not exist on type 'Square | Rectangle | Circle'
```

I could for example add a mapping between `Kinds` and `Shape`, and add some type annotations to the function:

```
type Kinds = "circle" | "rectangle" | "square";
type Shape = Square | Rectangle | Circle;
type ShapeKind = { "circle": Circle, "square": Square, "rectangle": Rectangle };

function createShape<T extends Kinds>(kind: T): ShapeKind[T] {
    switch (kind) {
        case "circle":
            return new Circle();
        case "rectangle":
            return new Rectangle();
        case "square":
            return new Square();
    }
}

createShape("circle").radius; //All good now
```

But having to create this mapping feels kind of nasty. I could also use type guards, but this feels pretty redundant, given that I know for sure the type of the Shape at the point I'm creating and returning it. Is there a nicer way to handle this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to *create* the mapping; you can *extract* it from your `Shape` type:

```
class Square {
  readonly kind = "square";
  size!: number;
}
class Rectangle {
  readonly kind = "rectangle";
  width!: number;
  height!: number;
}
class Circle {
  readonly kind = "circle";
  radius!: number;
}

type Shape = Square | Rectangle | Circle;
type Kinds = Shape["kind"]; // automatically

// return type is the consituent of Shape that matches {kind: K}
function createShape<K extends Kinds>(kind: K): Extract<Shape, { kind: K }>;
function createShape(kind: Kinds): Shape {
  switch (kind) {
    case "circle":
      return new Circle();
    case "rectangle":
      return new Rectangle();
    case "square":
      return new Square();
  }
}

createShape("circle").radius; // okay
```

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKCOBXMAnAptA3gKGtdYAJgPYB2IAntANYCWph0AvNAEQRKpqsDcu0EWgC80AQgBc0UogC2AIzQo+AX2yhIMAEppgAFzCkA5iAw48BEuSp0GzNuj0Hj3PngDutQroAWEqbIUlfm80WkNvXT9peUUVNXAoaABhWhRQU34LMkoaekYWVmBU9N5MolpECCiA2OxVbF0KAAcMWG8wFrsEZHRoAB9obUcjE37k4pM+Rs6AaTyYFjaOtABtVhtCVgBdPmwAM0RSPVoyaGACXTQlloAeGeg0AA9Lhhg514A+AAoNyRmASkkAFFnigwHobtc0AAaLC5Bh-aDKD58A5HXQnUhnC5XdotH55P7zQFwPEZPAQDy6YDeaAEhj-LD8PDASAYQoTbjiZl4fBoXSIFBY0hoNzjNImL7-Vy81kQdkOfQjLk88z8wXC0WDHRK5xSmUstlsDg9FW83noAVCqRa7pcfX8VT1c5oMCXKFfDkS7j-AB0YMIFQgfCAA)

The return type uses [`Extract<T, U>`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.5.1/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1461-L1464), a  built-in conditional type to filter a union `T` to only allow constituents assignable to another type `U`.

Notice that I used a single-call-signature [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) in `createShape()`, since the compiler is not really able to verify that the `switch` statement always returns something that matches the unresolved conditional type `Extract<Shape, { kind: K}>`.

Hope that helps; good luck!

---

UPDATE: You didn't ask for this, but if I were writing a function like `createShape()` I might store an object holdiing constuctors, and use indexed access to have the compiler verify type safety for me inside `createShape()`:

```
const verifyShapeConstructors = <
  T extends { [K in keyof T]: new () => { kind: K } }
>(
  x: T
) => x;

const badShapeConstuctors = verifyShapeConstructors({
    square: Square,
    circle: Rectangle, // error!
    rectangle: Circle, // error!
})

const shapeConstructors = verifyShapeConstructors({
  square: Square,
  rectangle: Rectangle,
  circle: Circle
});
type ShapeConstructors = typeof shapeConstructors;

type Instance<T extends Function> = T["prototype"];

type Shape = Instance<ShapeConstructors[keyof ShapeConstructors]>;
type Kinds = keyof ShapeConstructors;

function createShape<K extends Kinds>(kind: K): Instance<ShapeConstructors[K]> {
  return new shapeConstructors[kind]();
}
```

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#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-NRqdY5xTwYw2IwLAzTSzOY74fxOogW2oRzj-cTQ-Oz0DbegOzy6NHx1OE9NSYgkI6pfLZGgwAIqw70z2+bWhBgC-WfxshE+D0k3dF2ema4jG9206wjt0iBQpCkG540RAdI0mEc8nOR44jUQ80A7O5Cm9bgHgAOhQcpKj4IA)

In that I'm using a helper function `verifyShapeConstructors()` to make sure I don't mess up the constructor-holding object keys.  And I'm taking advantage of the fact that the compiler knows that class constructors like `Square` have a `"prototype"` property of the instance type... so it can use index access of that property to inspect a constructor's instance type.  (The built-in conditional type [`InstanceType<C>`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.5.1/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1491-L1494) acts similarly, but the compiler can't reason about conditional types as well as it can about index access).

All of that boils down to the fact that `createShape()` is now a one-line generic function that the compiler verifies as correct.

As I said, you didn't ask for this, but it might be of some interest.

Comment: Very cool, thanks (I know it says not to use comments like this, but it feels rude not to thank someone taking the time to help you) :)